# C# for loop to delete strings containing 'TJ' deletes only one of the Strings containing it

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create a method that deletes all Sales objects if they have a material description that includes "TJ" somewhere in the string. My problem is that when I create a List with four Sales, two of which include "TJ" in their description, only one is deleted. The one being deleted is not unique to the first one. if I delete the "TJ" from the first Sale the second Sale is then deleted correctly. Why does this occur? My method, along with the TestCase is below.

```
/// <summary>
/// This method deletes all sales with a 'TJ' material. 
/// </summary>
public void deleteTJ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < salesList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (salesList[i].material.Contains("TJ"))
        {
            salesList.Remove(salesList[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("FOUND IT");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not this time");
        }
    }
}

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDeleteTJ()
    {
        sale1.material = "ABJFSJTJ"; // Contains TJ
        sale2.material = "KTJANDKFH"; // Contains TJ
        sale3.material = "SADVUAWDJ"; // No TJ
        sale4.material = "JTNDBAYK"; // No TJ

        testList.Add(sale1);
        testList.Add(sale2);
        testList.Add(sale3);
        testList.Add(sale4);

        Modifier modifier = new Modifier(testList);

        Assert.IsTrue(testList.Count == 4);

        modifier.deleteTJ();

        Assert.IsTrue(testList.Count == 2);
        Assert.AreEqual("SADVUAWDJ", testList[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual("JTNDBAYK", testList[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging through your code, looking at what's being considered each time? Hint: after you've removed element 0 from the list, what index do you think KTJANDKFH has?

Comment: [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) only removes the first occurence

Comment: Loop backwards to avoid the indexing problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you edit the list during the loop. As soon as you remove one item the count gets changed.

There are two ways out of it - use one of of those:

1. Looping in reverse order (*List.Count-1 to 0*):

   ```
   for (int i = salesList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
   }
   ```
2. Removing values with Lambdas

   ```
   salesList.RemoveAll(s => s.material.Contains("TJ"));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

When you remove an item from the list all subsequent indexes are decremented.

```
0: ABJFSJTJ
1: KTJANDKFH
2: SADVUAWDJ
3: JTNDBAYK
```

When you remove the first index the list now looks like this:

```
0: KTJANDKFH
1: SADVUAWDJ
2: JTNDBAYK
```

The loop then increments `i` to 1, effectively skipping what was previously at index 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue stems from your loop.

```
for(int index = 0; index < collection.Count; index++)
     if(collection[index].Contains("TJ")
          collection.Remove(...)
```

So in your code, you are physically removing an index from your collection.  The problem though, is you're iterating through the array.  So you can solve a couple of ways:

- Create a copy of your collection, then remove from the one you aren't iterating through.
- You could use Linq, it would remove all the "TJ" contained elements from the collection.

Example 1:

```
var filter = collection;
for(int index = 0; index < collection.Count; index++)
    if(collection[index].Material.Contains("TJ"))
         filter.Remove(..);
```

Example 2:

```
var filter = collection.Where(item => !item.Material.Contains("TJ"));
```

Example 3:

```
  var filter = collection.RemoveAll(item => item.Material.Contains("TJ");
```

Comment: Why not `false == (item.Contains("TJ") == true)`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah, could do a ! to simplify.